# Python: Inherit/reuse specific methods from classes

Tags: python, class, inheritance, methods, code-reuse

I want a python class that is composed partly of specific methods from other classes which operates on `self` in the "composed class". How do I do that?

E.g. if I want to include specific methods from classA and classB in my new class "theClass":

```
    # Some classes to "inherit" from
    class classA(object):
        def methA1(self, value):
            self.attrib = value*1
        def methA2(self, value):
            self.attrib = value*2
    class classB(object):
        def methB1(self, value):
            self.attrib = value*3
        def methB2(self, value):
            self.attrib = value*4

    # The class I want to build
    class theClass(object):
        # WHAT TO DO HERE?
        # -------------------
        methA1 = classA.methA1
        methB2 = classB.methB2
        # -------------------
        # /WHAT TO DO HERE

        # add additional methods...
        def methC(self, value):
            self.attrib = value*5

    # I want the following behavior
    instance = theClass()
    instance.methB2(5)  # sets instance.attrib to 20
    instance.methA2(5)  # error, does not exist
```

Comment: That should work, at least in Python 3. What is your question/problem?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary That doesn't give the desired behaviour regarding `methA2` and `methB1`.

Comment: @delnan oh! Didn't see this line: `# error, does not exist`

Answer (score 3):

You could use mixins:

```
class MixinA1(object):
    def methA1(self, value):
        self.attrib = value*1
class MixinB2(object):       
    def methB2(self, value):
        self.attrib = value*4
class classA(MixinA1):
    def methA2(self, value):
        self.attrib = value*2
class classB(MixinB2):
    def methB1(self, value):
        self.attrib = value*3

# The class I want to build
class theClass(MixinA1, MixinB2):
    def methC(self, value):
        self.attrib = value*5
```

Mixins make sense if the Mixin class encapsulates some **unit of functionality** which you desire to add on to multiple classes.

If the methods don't naturally break down into units of functionality,
here is another alternative:

```
def methA1(self, value):
    self.attrib = value*1
def methA2(self, value):
    self.attrib = value*2
def methB2(self, value):
    self.attrib = value*4
def methB1(self, value):
    self.attrib = value*3
def methC(self, value):
    self.attrib = value*5

class classA(object):
    methA1 = methA1
    methA2 = methA2    
class classB(object):
    methB1 = methB1
    methB2 = methB2        
class theClass(object):
    methA1 = methA1
    methB2 = methB2
    methC = methC
```

This is very similar to the alternative you've already posted, except that it places except that it places all classes on an equal footing -- initially the methods are not associated with any particular class. This might be preferable so `theClass` is not "breaking encapsulation" by reaching in and nabbing a method from a class (such as `classA`) on which it does not explicitly depend.

Comment: Thanks. What I don't like about mixins is that they don't make it particularly clear what methods are available in the "new" class. If you have "self.thisMethod = classA.thisMethod", you know that it's available. I have around 15 methods that needs to be imported in different ways across around 10 other classes. But there might not be a way?